# Abstract List Functions in Racket/Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm completely stuck on a problem to write a function that does NOT use recursion, locals, or lambda. Only abstract list functions can be used. 
The function must input a list of positive integers, and output a list of integers that are strictly greater than 1.

any ideas on how to do this? I've never implemented abstract list functions on their own and I'm not sure which ones would be used in this case. 
Also, the language setting is Intermediate Student, no higher.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. but I have no idea what predicate I'd use when applying Filter

Comment: If you don't have a `>1` predicate, you can define one; and if you're not allowed to use `lambda` either, maybe you can use `curry` instead.

Comment: Is there a >1 predicate used? like would (filter >1 lst) work?

Comment: Maybe I have it: use the functions `-1+`, `positive?`, `1+` with `map`, `filter`, and `map`.

Comment: `1+` and `-1+` seem to be only in MIT-scheme (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228642/increment-and-decrement-operators-in-scheme-programming-language)